# How do I dynamically render new component after a change in previous component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a CMS in React where a user can enter N amount of pictures.

To do this, i created a `FileUploader` component. I can track when the user interacts with the component and read the file from this component.

I want to make it so there are N+1 `FileUploaders` rendered for N images in `this.state.images`

So if I have 3 images in the array, I want to render 4 `FileUploaders`

How do I do this with React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create a loop that renders the FileUploaders? You already has the number of images. Therefore, it should be easy to just do 
`for (let i = 0; i < this.state.images.length + 1; i++)`

Since you haven't presented some code to work with.. I just create some example code for you

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [images, setImages] = React.useState(["some stuff", "some stuff"]);

   return (
       <>
          {[...images, undefined].map(image => <FileUploaders />)}
       </>
   );
}
```

Notice that i add undefined at the end of the array, so we have one more entry to loop through. If you plan to use the image to something. You can just check if the image is undefined or not.

Comment: Thanks. That was my initial idea but i wandered if it was going to be performance taxing. Since you came up with the same solution i guess its a good enough way.